# Ubuntu 14.04 not working

Tags: 14.04

Maybe this already got answered but I have a problem. I recently upgraded my laptop to Ubuntu 14.04 64bit. When my laptop gets turned it asks for a password. I type it in and it goes back to the same menu and ask for the password again and again. I reboot the system and it did nothing. Please someone help me.

Comment: Suggest you give more details about the password request screen so that people know which password it is asking for. Also which menu do you mean? What does it have written on it?

Comment: It is the lock screen menu. It has my username ID and asking for a password user that and there is also a guest session under the password but it does the same thing when u hit the guest login

Comment: Suggest you access the terminal pressing Ctrl-Alt-F1, then view some logs: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxLogFiles - common useful logs are the X11 server log,  system log, kernel log. You can get to the GUI by Ctrl-Alt-F7.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/657662/ubuntu-14-04-is-getting-crashed/657670?noredirect=1#comment946546_657670)  may help you. It's a bug, I think, I'll have to search but this method will let you pass the login screen.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you create a new user. And try to log in. You can do it via console CNTRL+ALT+F2. adduser someusername

Comment: Thanks you for the advice but it didn't help it ask to login in I typed what u said and a username and it ask for a password when I type in that area nothing pops up (words). When I type my daily username and its password it still doesn't pop up.