# Ubuntu 14.04 is getting crashed

Tags: 14.04, gnome

I am on `ubuntu 14.04`, `I have 8 GB of RAM` , `Intel Core i5 processor`.
after installing `ubuntu14.04`, I installed `eclipse` and few more software,
When I restated it, I am not able to see my user account. my user account is gone, the only thing is left is guest account and I have not set any password for guest.
when I click in guest account, the screen turns black and the login screen appears again. I tried multiple times but no result.

This is not the first time.its been third time I have installed ubuntu14.04 within two days and I am facing the same problem again and again.

1. Is there any problem with ubuntu 14.04?
2. Should I install other version of ubuntu or other version of linux?
3. Which is best version of Linux for software development(java web
   application)?

Answer (score 0):

Your lightdm is corrupt probably. 
Press Ctrl + Alt + F1 to enter the CLI mode and log into it.
you can try 
`sudo dpkg --configure -a` 
If it doesn't work, `sudo apt-get install gdm` and set it as your default manager (more of a workaround)

Comment: I am not able to login in my system it self

Comment: But you get a login screen, right? use the Ctrl + Alt + F1 combination there and you will see a black screen with a `login:` type your username there and it should prompt you for a password

Comment: as you suggested did the same thing, but every time I am getting "I have no name". though I was able to run the above command. after executing the command, when I restarted the system. I having the same issue

Comment: Which command did you run? I've written two.
And you're getting "I have no name" because your userid is not mapping to your username. If you can run `whoami` you will get your userid and login using that number.